# Controlling AWS Canaries using the cli

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using the AWS CLI to speed up my workflow.  Does anyone know how to control CloudWatch Synthetic Canaries using the CLI?

I tried to call `describe-canaries` [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/synthetics/describe-canaries.html) in several ways via the AWS CLI and still can't get it to work.

Comment: It's going to be difficult for people to help if you don't provide any symptoms.

Comment: @jarmod there aren't any other than a list of commands listing.  For example when I try `aws synthetics describe-canaries` I don't get anything other than a list of commands

Comment: What does `aws --version` tell you? Are you using awscli v1?

Comment: `aws-cli/2.0.8 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/19.4.0 botocore/2.0.0dev12`  Version 2

Comment: Not sure which minor version introduced synthetics but you might want to upgrade to the latest (2.0.14) and retry.

Comment: That was it.  Needed to upgrade.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you indicated (it listed all supported services when you ran `aws synthetics`) suggests that the version of the AWSCLI you are running simply doesn't support the synthetics service. That could be because you are running v1 of the AWSCLI or it could be that you are running v2 but synthetics support was added in a more recent version.

Looks like the latter in your case, so the solution is to update to the latest AWSCLI v2 build.